# Replication jobs are not getting created after failover

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2019, transactional-replication

I added distribution database to the alwaysOn group of dist1 and dist2 server. I setup replication for the database which are part of AAG and act as a publisher( node 1 and node2) and subscriber resides on node2. replication works fine when pub db gets failover from node 1 to node 2 or vice versa.
However, If i failover distribution database from DIST1 to DIS2 then changes are not getting replicated. There's a SQL agent job(monitor and sync replication jobs) that crates all replication related SQL agent jobs on new primary post-failover but it's not creating any of the replication jobs. I tried to run steps manually but it throws following error.

Error 22022: SQL agent job 'XXXXXXXXXXX' does not exist in cache.

I tried to recreate replication jobs manually on on new primary but it didn't help. What could be reason for jobs couldn't find in cache.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved. I restarted sql agent service and it fixed the issue